# plotting on the y-axis in Mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, plot

I have another question about Wolfram Mathematica. Is there someone that knows how I can plot a graphic on the y axis?

I hope that the figure helps.

[image]

Comment: I have an update of my answer in case you need the `Filling` option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is to use a `ParametricPlot` like this:

```
ParametricPlot[
  {-y*Exp[-y^2], y}, {y, -0.3, 4},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, All},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  AspectRatio -> 1/4
]
```

[image: Example for plot with flipped axes]

Answer (score 9):

```
ParametricPlot[{5 Sin[y], y}, {y, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
                Frame -> True,  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

None of the answers given thus far can work with Plot's `Filling` option. Plot's output contains a `GraphicsComplex` in that case (which, incidentally, breaks Mr.Wizard's replacements). To get the filling capability (it doesn't work for a standard plot without filling) you could use the following:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Filling -> Axis] /.  List[x_, y_] -> List[y, x]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] 
   /. List[x_, y_] -> List[y, x]
```

[image]

Comment: @Thies It's a jungle out there  ;-)

Comment: @Thies and, apparently, it doesn't help to be first (even by 2 min only). Yours got accepted.

Comment: @Sjoerd I knew that the function reverse engineering skill would come in handy some day ;)

Comment: I already voted for this, so I cannot vote again, but good update!

Comment: You know it's funny, but I may have never noticed that ParametricPlot cannot not use Filling.

Comment: @Sjoerd My `RegionPlot` solution is able to manage filling, without the need to specify the `Filling ->` option. You should edit `None of the answers` by `_Almost_ none of the ...` :)

Comment: @belisarius First show that you can do the filling of my double sine example in that way ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd Done. Now add `almost` :)

Comment: @belisarius Close, but no cigar! Compare your and  my output carefully and you'll see that RegionPlot is rather inaccurate at at least two  prominent points (and I miss the two line colors)

Comment: @Sjoerd the carefully avoided regions measure zero in my Lebesgue ruler

Answer (score 9):

You can flip the axes after plotting with `Reverse`:

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 9}];

Show[g /. x_Line :> Reverse[x, 3], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

With a minor change this works for plots using `Filling` as well:

```
g1 = Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
g2 = Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}];

Show[# /. x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> x~Reverse~3,
     PlotRange -> Automatic] & /@ {g1, g2}
```

[image]

(It may be more robust to replace the RHS of `:>` with `MapAt[#~Reverse~2 &, x, 1]`)

---

#### As a Function

Here is the form I recommend one use.  It includes flipping of the original `PlotRange` rather than forcing `PlotRange -> All`:

```
axisFlip = # /. {
   x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> 
      MapAt[#~Reverse~2 &, x, 1], 
   x : (PlotRange -> _) :>
      x~Reverse~2 } &;
```

To be used like: `axisFlip @ g1` or `axisFlip @ {g1, g2}`

---

A different effect can be had with `Rotate`:

```
Show[g /. x_Line :> Rotate[x, Pi/2, {0,0}], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I feel the version that includes filling should be the definitive answer. The Rotate version is wrong in the same way as Alexey's: wrong sign of y.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun:

**ContourPlot** is another alternative. 
Using Thies function:

```
ContourPlot[-y*Exp[-y^2/2] - x == 0, 
            {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, 
            Axes -> True, Frame -> None]
```

[image]

**RegionPlot** is another

```
RegionPlot[-y*Exp[-y^2/2] > x,
           {x, -2.1, 2.1}, {y, -.1, 4.1}, 
           Axes -> True, Frame -> None, PlotStyle -> White, 
           PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 4}}]
```

[image]

And finally, a **REALLY** convoluted way using `ListCurvePathPlot` and `Solve`:

```
Off[Solve::ifun, FindMaxValue::fmgz];

ListCurvePathPlot[
 Join @@
  Table[
        {x, y} /. Solve[-y*Exp[-y^2/2] == x, y],
   {x, FindMaxValue[-y*Exp[-y^2/2], y], 0, .01}],
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 4}}]

On[Solve::ifun, FindMaxValue::fmgz];
```

[image]

**Off Topic**

Answer to Sjoerd's `None of the answers given thus far can work with Plot's Filling  option`.

Reply: Not necessary

```
f={.5 Sin[2 y],Sin[y]};
RegionPlot[Min@f<=x<=Max@f,{x,-1,1},{y,-0.1,2.1 Pi},
  Axes->True,Frame->None,
  PlotRange->{{-2,2},{0,2 Pi}},
  PlotPoints->500]
```

[image]

Comment: I thought about `RegionPlot` as well, but the syntax for that is different from `Plot` and more complex.  It is more familiar to be able to simply add: `Filling -> True`

Comment: @Mr. True! But this is just a little joke we are enjoying with Sjoerd :)

Comment: Yes @mr.Wizard, don't spoil our fun. This is our battle of wits.

Comment: @Sjoerd You shouldn't laugh at my efforts. I am now exploring `AxesStyle -> Thickness[.1]` with very good results

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you wanted the axis labels to show, you could just wrap the code for the original Plot in the Rotate function.